# Mesh colliders with SketchUp models (.dae)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, sketchup

I'm new to doing 3d games in unity, and I imported some 3d models that I made a while ago from SketchUp. I tried using the mesh collider, but my player (using character controller) just goes straight through the ground (that was what I imported). Not sure if I'm using the wriong collider, or?

Sorry if this is a stupid question, the Unity API didn't help.

**SCREENSHOTS**

[image: Inspector for Model]

Comment: Does the character have a rigidbody? Does the floor have a collider? Does the floor have a rigidbody?

Comment: Did you try to enable `Convex`?

Comment: Yes I did try convex, and no neither the character nor the floor have a rigidbody. Using convex or rigidbodies, or both, had no effect.